# DomDocument inserting CSS from file in style element

Tags: php, css, inline, domdocument

I am building a system where the requirement says no links to CSS are allowed. They do allow to place all CSS content within the style element.
I am using DOMDocument to build the XML/XHTML.

The CSS stylesheets are around 320 lines so I would pefer to construct them in separate CSS files and solve the insertion of the CSS content in the DomDocument build.

**Question:**
What is the best way of inserting an external CSS file content
and get it in place between the DOMDocument built style element?

**Index.php**

```
<?php

$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$html = $xml->createElement('html');
$xml->appendChild($html);

$head = $xml->createElement('head');
$html->appendChild($head);
//
$style = $xml->createElement(
  'style',
  'css-content....' // The CSS content from external file should be inserted here.
);
$style->setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
$head->appendChild($style);

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

**Main.css**

```
  body {
    background-color: pink;
  }
```

**Wanted result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head>

    <style type="text/css"> 

    body {
      background-color: pink;
    }

    </style>

  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

Add

```
$css = file_get_contents('main.css');
```

and change `$style` to:

```
$style = $xml->createElement('style', $css);
```

and it should work.